# Comparing two equal unsigned long in C evaluates to false

Tags: c, comparison, long-integer, unsigned

I am new to C and playing around with it. So I ended up in implementing the fibonacci code (iterative and recursive). I wrote a test function which should give me a green (my implementation works) or red. It says that I get the right return value but it's state is red. The two values should be both unsigned long. I am compiling on OSX with make

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long n);
void test_fibonacci(unsigned long n, unsigned long assertion);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test_fibonacci(1, 1);
    test_fibonacci(2, 1);
    test_fibonacci(3, 2);
    test_fibonacci(10, 55);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long result = 1;
    unsigned long lastResult;
    for (unsigned long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // save the current result to save it as the lastResult after this iteration
        unsigned long lastResultTmp = result;
        result = lastResult + result;
        lastResult = lastResultTmp;
    }
    return result;
}

void test_fibonacci(unsigned long n, unsigned long assertion)
{
    printf(
        "fibonacci(%lu): %lu    | %s | asserted: %lu\n",
        n,
        fibonacci(n),
        (fibonacci(n) == assertion) ? "green" : "red",
        assertion
    );
}
```

My Makefile

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: main

clean:
    rm -f main
    rm -Rf *.dSYM
```

Output:

```
fibonacci(1): 1    | green | asserted: 1
fibonacci(2): 1    | red | asserted: 1
fibonacci(3): 2    | red | asserted: 2
fibonacci(10): 55    | red | asserted: 55
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not getting the output that you are. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
fibonacci(1): 1    | green | asserted: 1
fibonacci(2): 2    | red | asserted: 1
fibonacci(3): 4    | red | asserted: 2
fibonacci(10): 3353    | red | asserted: 55
```

I was curious why, I so I ran it with valgrind. That quickly popped up this error:

```
==5619== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5619==    at 0x4005E7: test_fibonacci (fibonacci.c:31)
==5619==    by 0x400559: main (fibonacci.c:9)
```

So it looks like this has to do with an uninitialized variable getting read, which would give you the wrong values. That ultimately points us here:

```
unsigned long fibonacci(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long result = 1;
    unsigned long lastResult; // <---- LOOK HERE
    for (unsigned long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // save the current result to save it as the lastResult after this iteration
        unsigned long lastResultTmp = result;
        result = lastResult + result;
        lastResult = lastResultTmp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice that `lastResult` is uninitialized, but is read in the line

```
 result = lastResult + result;
```

So it looks like you need to initialize that value. Since that value corresponds to the previous Fibonacci number, you should initialize to zero. Doing that causes all the tests to pass.

Now, what exactly happened that caused it to look like you were getting the right answer but still failing? Notice that you called `fibonacci` twice in your testing code. My guess is that the first call to `fibonacci` - the one that got printed - just by sheer random chance happened to work correctly because for some reason the value in `lastResult` on the first call happened to be 0. However, I'm going to guess that the *second* call to `fibonacci` - the one that got compared against the expected result - did not return the same value as the first call because, for whatever reason, the value of `lastResult` wasn't 0 when that second call was made. That's the thing about undefined behavior - weird stuff like that can happen!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is totally right. I set i in the for loop to 3 und lastResult to 1 because of the first fibonacci numbers. That solves my problems. I totally have to check out valgrind.

Comment: @noeden Valgrind is a wonderful tool when you're getting started. My recommendation is (1) compile with warning settings cranked all the way up, (2) turn warnings into errors, and (3) run programs in Valgrind. You'd be amazed how many mistakes you'll catch this way. :-)

Comment: Agree with the need to initialize `lastResult` as not doing so leads to UB.  Yet I am suspicious that something else was causing OP to get the "right" answers, yet fail compare.  Hmmmm. UB is UB.  --> Aha, `fibonacci()` reported the correct answer every other time for OP.

Comment: @chux I just updated my answer with a plausible explanation for this behavior. What do you think?

Comment: Agreed - one truly weird UB.  As pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37954720/2410359), it does point out a weakness in OP's tests.  OTOH, I am impressed OP had a reasonable nice test code to begin with. UV to you and OP.

Answer (score 1):

fibonacci(1): 1    | green | asserted: 1

fibonacci(2): 3076653057    | red | asserted: 1

fibonacci(3): 3076653058    | red | asserted: 2

fibonacci(10): 1526988855    | red | asserted: 55

I am getting this output to your code. And I think this is because of the uninitialized variable lastResult. Because when I initialized it with 0 I got the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

OP [see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953949/comparing-two-equal-unsigned-long-in-c-evaluates-to-false#comment63357459_37954067).

This shows a subtle weakness in your test.  When `fibonacci(n)` was called, it provided the correct answer.  When `(fibonacci(n) == assertion)` was call it provided the wrong answer.  The weakness it that your test code called `fibonacci(n)` twice per test rather than once.  As your code had an uninitialized variable:  [@templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef)

```
// unsigned long lastResult;  // bad
unsigned long lastResult = 0; // good
```

With UB (undefined behavior) - that is possible.

---

Test code should have called the test function *once*:

```
unsigned long f = fibonacci(n);  
printf("fibonacci(%lu): %lu    | %s | asserted: %lu\n", 
    n, f, (f == assertion) ? `"green" : "red", assertion;
```

Then at least, with the errant `test_fibonacci()`, far more likely to get consistent results.

---

OTOH, this *weakness* pointed out could be a strength in that had the test only called `test_fibonacci()` once per loop, the UB may not have manifested itself in a bad way.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to change that.